# Updating UIImageView takes too much memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, core-graphics, grand-central-dispatch

I have a code block which is executed about every 20ms (it is a rendering callback method for a an audio unit of Core Audio); such method runs some calculations and updates the image of an UIImageView.
In order to force the UI to be refreshed, I schedule the setter for the image of the UIImageView in the main thread, as follows:

```
[audioUnit setOutputBlock:^() {
    // ...
    // some heavy calculations
    // ...
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{    
        imageView.image = images[index];
    });        
}];
```

Without the setter of the image, the app takes about 50mb of memory, whereas the refresh of the image makes it jump to about 300mb, resulting in a memory warning and crash on iPhone < 5.

What should be the best approach to face such issue?

Thanks a lot,
DAN

Comment: What is the image that you're setting? Is the image already loaded into memory?

Comment: images is an array of 110 UIImages, each of them has a resolution of 1136×640 and a size of about 20kb; I've tried loading them with both imageNamed as well as imageWithContentsOfFile.. same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your data set is rather large here. Think about it after the images are decompressed: 1136 height x 640 width x 4 bytes per pixel x 110 images = 320MB.  Unfortunately, image decompression is not fast/free, so if you want this to happen at 50Hz, you're going to have to play some tricks. For starters, you probably won't be able to keep all 110 images in memory at the same time, so stop trying to do that.

Also, don't use `-[UIImage imageNamed:]`. It aggressively caches decompressed versions of your image in a way that you have no control over. I would user `[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:]` so as to have maximum control over the lifecycle of your images.

If the decompression time is tolerable, then it may be as simple as keeping an array of paths to the images and then making the one `UIImage` object you need at the last possible minute. I suspect that 20ms is going to be a little too slow to do the decompression each time though.

Another option would be to pre-decompress the images, and then write the decompressed data to the application's cache directory on disk. This way, you're still loading from disk but it's a straight read and not a read-and-decompress every time. Note that this will necessarily consume ~320MB of disk storage. Not *too* horrible.

To take that one step further, with a few extra shenanigans, you might be able to get it so the images are on disk, and then the image objects in your application could point to mmap'ed memory regions corresponding to each file on disk. This way you let the virtual memory system decide what's important to have in memory and what's not, and you get that "for free." That seems like probably the best shot for this. (EDIT: I looked and it appears that UIImage already mmaps the images behind the scenes, so this suggestion might not be much help to you.)

Just one thing I noticed from the snippet you posted: You are capturing the whole array in the block closure, which means that every image in the array stays alive for the duration of that block (and some period of time longer, until libdispatch decides to release the block.) It probably won't be *enough* to avoid this (hence my recommendations above) but it certainly isn't helping to capture the whole array. Here's what I mean:

```
[audioUnit setOutputBlock:^() {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray* images = [NSArray array]; // or whatever
        // ...
        // some heavy calculations
        // ...
        UIImage* theOneImageWeNeed = images[index];
    }
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{    
        imageView.image = theOneImageWeNeed;
    });        
}];
```

That will keep the one image you need alive, and more aggressively release any other objects generated by the calculations.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! I'll go through your suggestions and try to improve the performances.
Just a note: the array of images is not created inside the output block as you wrote, but in the viewDidLoad method of the related view controller and the released in the viewDidDisappear.
Where I indicated "some heavy calculations" there's no code about the mentioned array.

Comment: Well there's your problem right there. All the images will be in memory the whole time your view is visible. Try keeping an array of paths and creating the images on demand.

Comment: What do you mean with an array of paths? If I create images on demand, it means that I have to allocate a new UIImage every 20ms on the base of the 'index' variable and release the previous one; do you think it will be more efficient?

Comment: It will *definitely* be more efficient in terms of memory use; whether it's fast enough is another question. The time required for allocating and deallocating the images is not going to be an issue, it's the decompression of the image that's going to be the "long pole". The core "memory problem" here is that you're attempting to keep ~320MB of image data in RAM all at once. Any viable solution to that "memory problem" will have to involve, you know, *not* doing that. Is there *any* predictability from one frame to the next? Or is it random?

Comment: There's no real predictability, even if it's very likely that if the current image has index 'x', the next one is 'x+1' or 'x-1' (I'm drawing a tachometer synchronized with the reproduction of an audio file). Moreover about 95% of the pixels of each image is transparent, in fact the image size is about 20/30kb.

Comment: Ah. A bunch of images is definitely *not* the best way to do this. You almost certainly want to draw this programmatically. If you can't feasibly draw it programmatically, you probably want to subset the image, and side-encode which portion of the whole screen needs to be replaced -- it doesn't matter how big the images are on disk, when it comes to memory use, it's about the raw, decompressed size and nothing else.